# How to scroll up and down in robotium in single line code

Tags: robotium

How we can scroll up and down in android apk using robotium .I want some simple code like we use in the Webdriver to navigate back which is a single line code.
Is there any single line code to scroll up and down.

Answer (score 0):

The solo object has a scrollDown() and scrollUp() method available on it.

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling down : `solo.scrollViewToSide(yourView, Solo.DOWN);`

For scrolling up : `solo.scrollViewToSide(yourView, Solo.UP);`